# How to convince Flow that a value meets the generic type?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have the following Flow-typed code:

```
/* @flow */

type Foo = 1;

const DefaultFoo: Foo = 1;

function getDefault<T: Foo>(): T {
  return DefaultFoo;
}
```

When I try to run it, here's the error I get:

```
8:   return DefaultFoo;
            ^ number literal `1`. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
7: function getDefault<T: Foo>(): T {
                                  ^ T
```

Here's a flow.org/try link: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAIwDc6AxnAHYDOGYAInlAIYCuMGYnABcREuSq1UUXozoYAlkzABzPBk49+GADwAVUUIB8ACgCUovWADeqMGABO63g8YcufAUNoBfIA

Could someone explain what's wrong with the code, and how I can convince Flow that `DefaultFoo` is indeed of type `T`?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that `DefaultFoo` is of type `T` is **wrong**.
Have a look at this example (`Bar` is our `T` in this case):

```
type Foo = {};

interface Bar extends Foo {
  bar(): void;
}

const DefaultFoo: Foo = {};
```

`Bar` extends `Foo`, so `Bar` is a `Foo` but not the other way around.
`DefaultFoo` is **not** a `Bar`